# What is the role and meaning of "posing" in this context?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, prepositions, parts-of-speech

Context:

> the article began with the news that he had been incapacitated since 1990, with his followers posing pictures of him and signing his correspondence with an automatic pen.

Question: what does the second 'with' mean and also 'posing picture'?

Comment: Are you certain it isn't "posting"?  Do you have a link to the original text?

Comment: I suspect they mean people dress like him and try to look like him.  Although it could mean that people near him propped him up to take his picture, making it look like he could stand on his own.